# Orthonormal Basis of Hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gram-schmidt

> Find an orthonormal basis of the hyperplane $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 0$.

So I understand how to use Gram-Schmidt to solve this, but I'm having issues finding the basis to start with. Is it as follows:

$x_1 = -x_2 - x_3 - x_4 - x_5$, therefore our basis is:
${\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}},{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}},{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}},{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}}$ 
And from there, we do G-S?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Yes they satisfy the equation, are 4 and are clearly linearly independent thus they span the hyperplane.

Yes to get an orthonormal basis you need Gram-Schmidt now. Let obtain a orthonormal basis before by GS and then normalize all the vectors only at the end of the process. It will simplify a lot the calculation avoiding square roots.

Are you aware about how Gram-Schmidt works?

Note that to simplify further you could choose

$${\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}},{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}},{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}},{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}}$$

or similar in such way to satisfy all the conditions with the advantage to have some of them orthogonal.